Reference for homotopy and homology theory of topological groups
I am looking for references which deal with the homotopy theory and homology theory of general topological groups, not necessarily compact, or anything. I am eyeing towards certain infinite-dimensional symmetry groups appearing in geometry.

You will probably get better answers if you ask about a specific infinite-dimensional symmetry group, e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper%27s_theorem.
